# Adding a parameter to Implicit Reads building a case class from JSON with Play

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I need to add a static value to a case class I'm building from JSON with Play framework. I can add a constant value like this:

```
implicit val userRead: Reads[UserInfo] = (
  Reads.pure(-1L) and
  (JsPath \ "firstName").readNullable[String] and
  (JsPath \ "lastName").readNullable[String] 
)(UserInfo.apply _)
```

But I can't see how I could pass a variable into the implicit Reads at the time it is called. I'm pretty new to Scala so probably missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that your `UserInfo` is something like this:

```
case class UserInfo(id: Long, firstName: Option[String], lastName: Option[String])
```

You only need to tweak a bit `userRead`:

```
def userRead(id: Long): Reads[UserInfo] = (
  Reads.pure(id) and
  (JsPath \ "firstName").readNullable[String] and
  (JsPath \ "lastName").readNullable[String]
)(UserInfo.apply _)
```

And then make use of it explicitly when decoding the json:

```
json.as[UserInfo](userRead(12345L))
```

Or, alternatively, instantiate the `Reads` making it `implicit`:

```
implicit val userRead12345 = userRead(12345L)

json.as[UserInfo]
```

Answer (score 0):

there is a simpler solution:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
```

add all values that have static default values at the end:

```
case class UserInfo(firstName:String, lastName:String, id:Long = -1)
```

Use `play-json format` with default values:

```
object UserInfo{

    implicit val jsonFormat: Format[UserInfo] = Json.using[Json.WithDefaultValues].format[UserInfo]
}
```

And use it like this

```
val json = Json.toJson(UserInfo("Steve", "Gailey"))

println(json.validate[UserInfo])
```

See here the whole [example](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/wqaZA9p/0)